# Как считать комментарий в PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, комментарии

В многих фреймворках и библиотеках используется ввод какой-то информации (типа конфиг) в комментарий, а php как-то его считывает и использует эту информацию.

К примеру, когда ты создаешь плагин для WordPress, нужно добавить комментарий с некоторой информацией о плагине в его начало. Как через PHP считать информацию из комментария?

Comment: Спарсить, как обычно в принципе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю где в `WP` комментарии ставятся. Но в `PHP` есть такое:

```
<?php
/** 
* A test class
*
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/
class TestClass { }

$rc = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
var_dump($rc->getDocComment())
?>
```

**Результат:**

```
/** 
* A test class
*
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/
```

---

Пример из документации [getDocComment](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

Answer (score 2):

Открыть файл php как обычный файл и прочитать иформацию из него, строка за строкой. WordPress так и делает.

Вот код для считывания текущего файла php в массив

```
$lines = file( __FILE__ );
```

Дальше с этим массивом строк можно делать что угодно.